# group_concat() on bit fields returns garbage in Mysql

Tags: mysql

***Table Structure***

```
CREATE TABLE `academicyears` (
  `id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `campusid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `academicyear` text NOT NULL,
  `month` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `flag` bit(1) DEFAULT b'1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

***My Query***

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ay.`flag`) 
FROM academicyears ay
GROUP BY ay.`campusid`
```

***Result***

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this;)

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ay.`flag` + 0) 
FROM academicyears ay
GROUP BY ay.`campusid`
```

And check reference [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-field-literals.html).